# How to initiate "npm start" via javascript file

Tags: javascript, npm

My project has a json file with following lines:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm test",
```

Till now I ran it from vscode terminal -> `npm start` command.
Now, I added a js file to the project, with a button, and I want that `npm start` will run on button clicking.
I know how to add an event listener, but how can I link between `npm start` and the js file?

Comment: VSCode has build in buttons for running NPM scripts via: Explorer -> NPM scripts

Comment: Where is your js running, browser or on a node server?

Comment: js run in the browser

Comment: @reyno can you please elaborate your answer? thanks!